# ContinueWith not waiting for task to complete

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

I have a function (below) that I retrieve data from an API. If I set a breakpoint at the line that deserializes it, then I can see that it is populated with data which is great.

When I continue on, it goes into the second function (below) and it throws an error. The error says next to it `Not yet computed`, and therefore throwing an exception.

When I do it with a small list it works just fine (I presume its cos it's a small set of data).

How is this possible when I'm using `ContinueWith` (waiting for the task to complete)?

```
    public static async Task<Data> GetAllCardsInSet(string setName)
    {
                setName = WebUtility.UrlEncode(setName);
                var correctUri = Path.Combine(ApiConstants.YugiohGetAllCardsInSet, setName);
                Console.WriteLine();
                using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
                {
                    var response =
                        await httpClient.GetAsync(correctUri);
                    var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    var cardData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CardSetCards>(result);
                    for (int i = 0; i < cardData.Data.Cards.Count; i++)
                    {
                        cardData.Data.Cards[i] = FormatWords(cardData.Data.Cards[i]);
                    }
                    return cardData.Data;
                }
    }


    private void GetYugiohCardsAndNavigate(string name)
    {
    var cardSetData = YugiohRequester.GetAllCardsInSet(_selectedCardSet.Name).ContinueWith((result) =>
                {
                    //var cards = await YugiohRequester.GetAllCardsInSet(_selectedCardSet.Name);
                    try
                    {
                        this.mainPage.NavigateToYugiohCardListPage(result.Result);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        HelperFunctions.ShowToastNotification("Trading Card App", "Sorry, we could not fetch this set");
                    }

                });
}
```

Comment: What will be happened if you avoid `ContinueWith` just await `GetAllCardsInSet` method?

Comment: Gives me a null reference exception

Comment: Can you please investigate what will be happened if you return `await Task.FromResult(cardData.Data)` instead `cardData.Data`.

Comment: Your `GetAllCardsInSet` is throwing an exception. Check the `IsFaulted` `result` parameter in the ContinueWith block to see if `GetAllCardsInSet` threw an exception

Comment: @magna_nz: Don't ever use `ContinueWith`. Use `await` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `GetAllCardsInSet` method no need to change.
But using of this method can be refactored.
Method `GetAllCardsInSet` return `Task` and you not observed the completion of the this `Task`.
You need to check is `Task` completes succesfully, easiest approach to use `await` keyword. Awaiting task will unwrapp returned value or throw exception if task completed with exception.

For using `async/await` in the `GetYugiohCardsAndNavigate` change method signature to aynchronous and returning `Task`

```
private async Task GetYugiohCardsAndNavigate(string name)
{
    try
    {
        var cardSetData  = await YugiohRequester.GetAllCardsInSet(_selectedCardSet.Name);
        this.mainPage.NavigateToYugiohCardListPage(cardSetData);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        HelperFunctions.ShowToastNotification("Trading Card App", 
                                              "Sorry, we could not fetch this set");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you called an async method in a sync method without `Wait`. It should have been done like:

```
            YugiohRequester.GetAllCardsInSet(_selectedCardSet.Name).ContinueWith((result) =>
            {
                //var cards = await YugiohRequester.GetAllCardsInSet(_selectedCardSet.Name);
                try
                {
                    this.mainPage.NavigateToYugiohCardListPage(result.Result);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    HelperFunctions.ShowToastNotification("Trading Card App", "Sorry, we could not fetch this set");
                }

            }).Wait();
```